# Capture the concept of a subspace in the category of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Is it possible to capture the concept of a subspace in **Top**? By that I mean the following: You are given a morphism $i:Y\to X$ in **Top**. Is it possible to tell if $Y$ can be regarded as subspace of $X$ with $i$ being the embedding map where you only may use the information the category **Top** can provide? So you have access to all objects and morphisms but you don't have the functor sending them to **Set**. So in particular you can't access the elements of a topological space and the open sets.

For sure such an $i$ has to be injective. This can be checked by simply checking if $i$ is monic (which is a category theoretic property). But only knowing that $i$ is injective is not enough because $Y$ could have a much finer topology than the actual subspace. So what is left is checking if $Y$ has the coarsest topology making $i$ continuous. And this has to be done by means of **Top**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get subspace embeddings, instead of monomorphisms, you have to consider [extremal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extremal+monomorphism) / [regular](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+monomorphism) monomorphisms.

Recall that a regular monomorphism is a monomorphism that arises as an equalizer. For a subspace inclusion $X\subset Y$ you may consider two arrows $f,g\colon Y \to \{ 0,1 \}$, where $\{ 0, 1 \}$ carries the indiscrete topology, $f$ maps everything to $1$ and $g$ maps to $1$ the elements of $X$. Then the inclusion $i\colon X\hookrightarrow Y$ is the equalizer of $f$ and $g$.

In the other direction, any equalizer of two arrows $f,g\colon Y\to Z$ is some subspace $X\subset Y$.

Comment: I think you want to give $\{0,1\}$ the indiscrete/trivial topology, rather than the discrete topology. Otherwise $g$ is not usually continuous.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard Yes, you are absolutely right. Thank you!